# How to clear header manager programmatically

Tags: jmeter

I have a TestPlan

```
Thread-group
 HttpSampler
  pre-processor
  HttpHeaderManager[empty]
  HttpRequestDefaults[empty]
  Post-processor
```

I am using a pre-processor script to add headers dynamically to headerManager from reading a json file. it goes well .

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header
int min = args[0].toInteger()
int max = args[1].toInteger()
int random =  min + (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));
// here 'inputjson' referring to slurped json object

 inputjson.Headers.each{
        it.each{    key,value -> sampler.getHeaderManager().add(new Header(key.replace('$random',random.toString()),value.replace('$random',(random+2).toString())));
               }
    }
```

the issue is, if a thread loop count is 3, then the set of headers are adding 3 times.

then I added a post processor script

```
sampler.getHeaderManager().clear()
```

This time initial[loop-1] run is going fine, next[loop-2] loop is a clear request with no headers. how can I achieve, each request will go with only 1 set of headers

Comment: what if you add `sampler.getHeaderManager().clear()` above your `inputjson.Headers.each{` loop in pre-processor?

Comment: let me check !!!.. its nice idea

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working example - `HeaderManager.clear()` did not work, but removing the header by its name did its job.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header;
sampler.getHeaderManager().removeHeaderNamed("Authorization");
sampler.getHeaderManager().add(new Header("Authorization", "Bearer " + vars.get("token")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to remove headers programatically - first, getting the headers count and looping till the end of headers count.

```
int headers_size = sampler.getHeaderManager().size();
log.info("headers_size: "+ headers_size);
while(headers_size > 0) {
  log.info("header to be removed:"+ sampler.getHeaderManager().get(0));
  sampler.getHeaderManager().remove(0);
  headers_size = sampler.getHeaderManager().size();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This will done by

adding `sampler.setHeaderManager(new HeaderManager())` just before the headerManger add section .

each time a new HeaderManger will get added and will be used. Not sure it is the best solution , but its a working solution.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use the f$%$ing method `HeaderManager.clear()` which existence I still don't get, and do not do that in a post-processor, better do this in your preprocessor before adding headers to Header Manager.

```
headerMgr = sampler.getHeaderManager();
while(headerMgr.getHeaders().iterator().hasNext()) {
    headerName = headerMgr.getHeaders().iterator().next().getStringValue().split("\\s+")[0];
    headerMgr.removeHeaderNamed(headerName);
}
```

Comment: this leads to an infinit loop in my sample - had to kill Java